# Am I estimating $p$ of this distribution correctly?

Tags: statistics, estimation, binomial-distribution

So my textbook has this in it:

```
x     |  0 |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |
---------------------------------------------------
freq. | 12 | 28 | 28 | 17 |  7 |  4 |  2 |  2 |  0 |
```

And its claiming that this is roughly distributed over $B(10, 0.2)$

I want to try and get these values so I calculated sample mean and variance:

- $X$ bar = 2.09
- $S^2$ = 2.41

The mean seems ok since $10 * 0.2 ≈ 2.09$ but a problem happens when I try to estimate the proportion:

- Assume $X$ ~ $B(n, p)$
- $2.09 ≈ np$
- $2.41 ≈ np(1-p)$
- therefore: $np(1-p)/(np) ≈ 2.41/2.09$
- therefore: $1-p ≈ 1.15$
- therefore: $p ≈ -0.15$ ???????

Is it just possible for the estimator to get it completely wrong or have I done something wrong?

Comment: Something is certainly wrong, as $p$ must be positive. Check your work and compare against anything you have.

Answer (score 1):

The value of $n$ is $n=10$ due to $Bin(n,p)=Bin(10,0.2)$.

$10\cdot p=2.09 \Rightarrow p=0.209 \Rightarrow 1-p=0.791$

The theoretical frequency is

$$f(x)= 100\cdot \binom{10}{x}\cdot 0.209^x\cdot 0.791^{10-x}$$

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline x&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10 \\  \hline  f(x)&9.59&25.33&30.12&&&&&0.1&0.01 \\ \hline \end{array}$$

I have left some blanks for you.

Finally you have to round the numbers to the nearest integer I would say. But as you can read in the comments BruceET has a different opinion.

Comment: Why do values of $f(x)$ need to be integers?

Comment: @BruceET I assumed that the frequencies can be only integers like cars, people, .. due to the given data. Maybe $f(x)\in \mathbb R$, but I don´t see any reason why it should be like this.

Comment: Data are discrete counts, but I don't see that $f(x)$ needs to be integers. And in general, expected counts can be fractions. (A common error in doing a chi-squared goodness-of-fit test is to round expected counts to integers.)

Comment: @BruceET I have included your doubts in my answer. Thanks for posting them.